# Webapi controller without authentication

Tags: microservices, asp.net-core-webapi

I have some controllers in a webapi core project that requires authentication. I want to create another controller that will not require authentication and will be accessible from outside. How can I create such a controller without authentication?

Answer (score 1):

Assume that you've done the process of verifying the user for authentication/authorization.

The [AllowAnonymous] attribute will skip authentication and authorization during an access request to a controller decorated with this attribute or to a specific action method decorated with this attribute

```
 [Authorize]
 public class SampleController : BaseController
 {
     [AllowAnonymous]
     public IActionResult Get() { ... }
     public IActionResult Post() { ... }
 }
```